# Finding the nth anchor tag in a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following peice of code which binds click events to multiple anchor tags present in a div.

I want to determine which link was clicked (1st link or 2nd link or nth link) so that I can pass it to myFunction.

```
function bindClickEvent(){
    $.each($("#links > li > a"), function(index, element){
        $(element).click(function(event){
        myFunction(linkID);
        });
    });
}
```

The reason I use the above type of function is because the anchor tags created in links div are dynamically created. i.e building html using other function

Comment: _"the anchor tags created in links div are dynamically created"_ Then you should use `.on()`'s delegated event syntax.

Comment: Instead of `linkID` put `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy we must live in a parallel universe with mine 5 seconds lagging B-)

Comment: Does `index` not suit that need? Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: linkID is the `nth` anchor tag present in the div

Comment: So maybe you want `$(this).id` ? Instead of `linkID`.

Comment: `index()` ? It isn't a function, it is an integer. From the documentation I linked: "... the current loop iteration, beginning from 0."

Comment: @MS_SL Yes, index variable works. I made a mistake when I tried with index and wrote $(this).index() instead of just the variable

Comment: @RHLK please do not forget to mark an answer as the correct answer if they answered your question

Answer (score 3):

try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wo3o55yL/1/

```
<div>
    <a href="">One</a>
    <a href="">Two</a>
    <a href="">Three</a>
    <a href="">Four</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunction($('a').index(this));
});


function myFunction(id) {
    alert('my function - ' + id);
}
</script>
```

First point will be indexed with zero so thats why `one is 0` and `two is 1` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You should use event delegation to achieve this goal, like this:

**Given HTML:**

```
<div id="links" >
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {

    // Just a simulation for dynamic links
    setTimeout(function() {
        var as = [];

        for(var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i) {
            as.push('<a href="">Element-' + (i+1) + '</a>');
        }

        $('#links').html(as.join('<br />'));
    }, 2000);

    // Event delegation
    $('#links').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        myFunction($('a').index(this));
    });


    function myFunction(id) {
        alert('my function - ' + id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also, see working demo http://jsfiddle.net/g8k1csz9/

```
<ul id="links">              
    <li><a href="#">Something1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something4</a></li>
</ul>

$( "#links li a" ).click(function() {
  var index = $('#links li a').index(this);
  myfunction(index);
});

function myfunction(index){
alert(index);
}
```